# How to get the caret position at rtf code in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I'm trying to insert a table in `RichTextBox`, using `C# Windows Form`.
I made the code which makes a table, but I can't insert that in middle of text.
Below is my code.

```
public void richTextBox1_InsertTable(int row, int column)
{
    StringBuilder tableRTF = new StringBuilder();

    tableRTF.Append(@"\trowd");
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            tableRTF.Append(@"\cellx" +  (j + 1) * 1000);
        tableRTF.Append(@"\intbl \cell \row");
    };
    tableRTF.Append(@"\pard");

    richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Insert(@POINT@,tableRTF.ToString());
}
```

@POINT@ is `caret position` at rtf code. but I don't know how to get it...
Is there any ways to get `caret position` at rtf code? Or is there any good ways to make the table in `RichTextBox`?

Comment: You have to [select text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660239/1997232) and then you can modify [selected rtf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852677/1997232).

Comment: I'm sorry.. i have no idea how to use those...